# OOP Object Constructor arguments

Tags: parameters, constructor

When should I pass arguments to the object's constructor? Which criteria do you use to pass them to the constructor instead of arguments in object's methods?

Answer (score 2):

Pass things to the constructor that are immutable properties of the object. When possible, make all object properties immutable. Taken to its full extent, this allows the entire objet to be immutable.

Immutable properties, assigned at construction, avoid a variety of race conditions (particularly in multi-threaded environments) and helps ensure that the object is always consistent, eliminating the possibility of many kinds of errors. By forcing properties to be defined at construction, you avoid extensive error-checking code. Once the entire object can be immutable, there are opportunities for sharing equivalent objects, improving memory performance.

If a parameter is not an immutable property of the object, then assigning it in the constructor is merely a convenience. In general, it should be assigned with a setter to reduce code complexity (since the setter is required anyway). If the constructor is called very often, then the convenience of parameter may be worth this extra complexity.

Comment: Immutable? Like database connections to a model object? Thank you.

Comment: Immutable means that the object cannot change in ways visible to callers. If I ask an immutable string for its third character, then that will be its third character for the entire life of the string. A mutable string is one that could change over time. Internal data structures such as caches are not part of mutability, so it doesn't mean that the literal memory of the object never changes. But from the outside world, you will always get the same answers to the same questions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Answer (score 1):

When my object is very simple (1 or two attributes) i may provide a constructor with these arguments.

But most of the time, default constructor and i set my attributes with the setters.

Comment: Ok, a simple object is a criteria... Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a very robust setup and could lead to nullPointer errors. (imagine someone else using your classes who doesn't know that he/she needs to set everything with the setters).

Comment: Ok, good point, too much Spring and Dependency injection ;-)  but in the case of complex object with dependency, i would use a builder pattern instead of a constructor with 10 arguements.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pass arguments to the class constructor when instantiating the class with the `new` keyword (this may differ depending on language).

For example (opting for the C / Java / C# style here)

```
MyClass class = new MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

On re-reading your question, I tend to use constructor arguments for absolutely required resources. That way, you know your object must have certain properties or resources available.

Comment: "... required resources ..." I thought about it but was not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to initialize all the basic building blocks of the object in the constrctor.
But sometimes, The object contains to many elements, thus making the argument list for the constructor too long.
I follow this guideline: If the argument list for a constructor is more the 5 elements,
the initalization of a new object is divided into constructor arguments & set methods.